# Using google apps with separate google account

Tags: google-account, google, accounts

I have two Google accounts. One use for certain google stuff and one for other.
I want to be able to use Google apps on my android phone with both of those accounts. I want to use some with one account (e.g. email) and another with the other account (e.g. play store). I am aware that I can create different users on my phone with different google credentials but this is not a simple and usable option. Is there any other way?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible without some Xposed magic. By default, Android keeps a centralized info of accounts, so every app (which wants to see the accounts) can see all the accounts.

Comment: Then can i not have two google accounts and choose each time?